# What is a K-B6-KEY Header?

Tags: networking, smtp

Doing some networking related challenges and came across this header.
What is this header for, and where do they use it?
Didn't find an answer on Google.

Answer (score 1):

This can be find in the Header of E-mail sent by the site. Try to trigger an e-mail from the corresponding site to your inbox and go through the header section of mail